# Why am i getting "phantom" readings from a flowmeter?

Tags: arduino-uno, raspberrypi

I have 2 flowmeters hooked up to my arduino uno.  They're set to read beer volume as beer flows through them.  Everything is working great, except i'm getting phantom readings.  I have the arduino communicating w/ a raspberry pi over USB, and i set my python script on the pi to start logging when reads are taking place.  i'm getting reads of 1-3ml every 15-30 mins (with 1 fluke of 16ml).  i have 2 flowmeters connected, but only 1 is sending these pulses.

there is nothing coming out of the taps, and everything inside the kegerator is bone dry.  i don't know what to look for...

Comment: As is, this looks too vague to be answered.  Please edit your question to at least give  the model numbers of flowmeters.  Presumably they can jitter and/or lack hysteresis?  If the problem may be in code, then include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of code that exhibits the problem

Comment: Try swapping the meters, and see if the problem is with the meter (or keg), or the rest of the system.

Comment: It could be a dodgy earth connection.